# PHP & JSON - How to insert an associative array into an associative array with a name for each new array thats not 0,1,2,3 etc

Tags: php, css

is there any library that can inspect and display what are the arguments that a method takes?`{"0":
{"sessionID":"9",
 "sessionName":"dataName0",
 "sessionCount":100,
 "sessionDC":"12:11AM - Jun 06 11",
 "sessionDM":"01:00AM - Jan 01 70",
 "sessionActive":"1"},
 "1":
{"sessionID":"10",
 "sessionName":"dataName1",
 "sessionCount":100,
 "sessionDC":"05:04PM - Jun 06 11",
 "sessionDM":"01:00AM - Jan 01 70",
 "sessionActive":"1"},
 "userID":"1",
 "userName":"Ezra",
 "total":2}`

Comment: Please guys, let's not bash our new users? If you downvote, at least leave some comments on how to improve this question.

Answer (score 2):

Your title doesn't match your question, but I can answer the part about inspecting the arguments that a method takes:

```
func_get_args()
```

Gets an array of the function's argument list.

This function may be used in conjunction with func_get_arg() and func_num_args() to allow user-defined functions to accept variable-length argument lists.

As for the title:

Any array can contain a named sub array.

```
$arr = array("name" => "bob")

$person = array();
$person['data'] = $arr;

Array([data] => Array([name] => bob))
```